# How do you set a button to stay disabled unless two events are true in javaFX?

Tags: java, javafx

I have two separate textProperty listeners to listen to changes on my javaFX application so it can update a password strength icon, and a valid username icon respectively. Both functions take their data from a TextField (username) and a PasswordField (password). These are the listeners:

```
if(loginCheck.passwordValidator(password.getText()) == -1) {
    passwordImg.setImage(fail);
    submit.setDisable(true);
}

if(loginCheck.usernameValidator(username.getText()) == -1) {
    usernameImg.setImage(fail);
    submit.setDisable(true);
}
```

I'm trying to get the button (submit) to stay disabled when one or the other functions return -1. I can disable the button when either function has the correct output, but I can't enable the button again without using separate submit.setDisable(false) calls; which falls flat on its face when one listener is trying to enable the button, when it should still be disabled according to the other listener. Is there a way I can set the button to ALWAYS stay off unless both events are true?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just combine your conditions using logic OR operation -- `||`

```
boolean invalidPassword = loginCheck.passwordValidator(password.getText()) == -1;
boolean invalidUsername = loginCheck.usernameValidator(username.getText()) == -1;

if (invalidPassword) {
    passwordImg.setImage(fail);
}

if(invalidUsername) {
    usernameImg.setImage(fail);
}

// if at least one of variables is true then submit will be disabled
submit.setDisable(invalidPassword || invalidUsername);
```

Comment: Top man! Definitely feel like a mug for over-complicating things by thinking that I was missing an obvious method of linking the two listeners without considering boolean's. But thank you nonetheless!